# ejs-pager click and dropDownChanged method call simultaneously issue

Tags: angular, ejs

I am using **ejs-pager** in **Angular**. But facing problem during **dropDownChanged** method calling as it also calls **click** method. is there any way to prohibit this nature?
there is a condition that both pageChange and dropDownChanged custom methods can't be called simultaneously.

```html
<ejs-pager #pager (click)="pageChange($event)" (dropDownChanged)="dropDownChanged($event)"
                     [locale]='locale' [pageCount]='pageSettings.pageCount'
                     [pageSize]='pageSettings.pageSize'
                     [pageSizes]='pageSettings.pageSizes'
                     [totalRecordsCount]='totalCount' *ngIf="apiSupportsPagination">
</ejs-pager>
```

Comment: Please post error or code snippet , trying to explain , it will be useful for answering .

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I have added code snippet.